# Aura External Schema and DTD's

Tags: aura, aura-attribute

I would like to import aura schema/DTD into my IDE, do salesforce provide the DTD for aura? where I could find it?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Maybe there's an alternative method?

Comment: webstorm intellij IDE